# Rendering problem cross-reference equation in r markdown HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I usually reference equations in `rmd` using `\label{}` and `\eqref{}` combination. (I know `\@ref`, but this seems only works in `bookdown::pdf_document` or `bookdown::html_document`) For example,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Blended"
date: '2019 3 14 '
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = "#>")
```

\begin{equation} \label{eq:test}
  Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

Equation $\eqref{eq:test}$ works in PDF, but does not works in HTML.
````

This works well in `pdf` document.

[image]

However, when rendering `html`, it gives `(???)`, not `(1)`:

[image]

---

I think this is related to this issue: [Support LaTeX environments in Markdown -> HTML conversion](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1938), i.e. MathJax occurs the error.

But I cannot see any solution of this.

*Is it possible to use `\eqref{eq:}` normally in html document?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following script at the beginning of your document body:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }
});
</script>
```

It configures MathJax to automatically number equations. More details [here](https://mathjax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering).